# How do you index an array inside a JSON with an Oracle 12c query?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, indexing, oracle12c

I have a table "move" with one column "move_doc" which is a CLOB. The json stored inside has the structure:

```
{
moveid : "123",
movedate : "xyz",
submoves: [
{
submoveid: "1",
...
 },
{
submoveid : "2",
...
}
]
}
```

I know I can run an Oracle 12c query to access the submoves list with:

`select move.move_doc.submoves from move move`

How do I access particular submoves of the array? And the attributes inside a particular submove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use Oracle functions `json_query` and/or `json_value` like this:

```
SELECT json_value(move_doc, '$.submoves[0].submoveid' RETURNING NUMBER) FROM move;
```

returns `1`.

```
SELECT json_query(move_doc, '$.submoves[1]') FROM move;
```

would return the second JSON element, i.e. something like

```
{
submoveid : "2",
...
}
```

`json_value` is used to retrieve a scalar value, `json_query` is used to retrieve JSON values. You might also want to have a look at `json_table` which returns an SQL result table and thus can be used in Joins.

See [this Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6277) for more examples

Comment: That link is for Oracle Database 12cR1. The corresponding doc for 12cR2 is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/function-JSON_QUERY.html#GUID-D64C7BE9-335D-449C-916D-1123539BF1FB).

Answer (score 3):

Beda here from the Oracle JSON team.

We have added a new multi-value index in release 21c allowing you to index values from a JSON array. Obviously, 21c is brand new and you want to know how to do this in older releases: Functional indexes (using JSON_Value function) are limited to a single value per JSON document and therefore are not capable to index array values. But: there is a 'JSON search index' which indexes your entire JSON document and therefore also values in the array. Another solution is to use a materialized view usign JSON_Table. This will expand the array values into separate rows.Then you can add a regular B-Tree index on that column.

Sample code here:
JSON indexing with functional indexes and JSON search index
https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_HN507PELCEEJGVNW4Q61L34DS.html

JSON and materialized views
https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_HYMB1YBP4CPMG6T6MXY5G9X5L.html

Answer (score 0):

From what I've looked, In Oracle,  you can index the "whole array" as a single index entry, but not individual elements of an array.

NoSQL databases like MongoDB, Couchbase, Cassandra have "array/collection" indexes which can index individual elements or fields of objects within an array and query them.